# i can not create react-native,when i use code react-native init App1 expressing this error

Tags: react-native

when i use code react-native init App1 expressing this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQxo.png)

Comment: Please provide some more context as to what you are doing, and why this error is unexpected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command:

```
npx react-native init project_name
```

Or see your development setup (system variables, programs installation, re-install these programs), and provide more info, like version of your project, version of programs/setups/emulators/devices...